# Grammatical name and expression

Tags: grammaticality

Question (d) The reader's frame of mind:

(i) What grammatical name is given to describe the above expression?

(ii) What is its function in the sentence?

[image: screenshot]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFME1.jpg)

Comment: The passage shown does not include the phrase *the reader's state of mind* except in the question. Can you post the entire passage?

Comment: It is called a quote, anything spoken or written that is repeated without change. The quote marks are the signal for us as readers. In this case, we know without reading the test passage that you saw these words "the reader's...mind" right there in the passage.

Comment: I don't think there's enough context to answer your question, based on the material you've presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the writing class I teach, I refer to it simply as the writer's "audience," e.g., "know and speak to your audience."  You could also call it "perspective", I suppose.

Comment: And if that's not the information for which you are asking, I agree with prior comments that you have not provided enough information.